# How can I apply a event listener to an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So I am trying to make a bookmarklet that when you hover over things, they light up, and this is what I have so far

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
h1length = h1.length;
for (var i=0; i <= h1.length; i++) 
{
    h1[i].addEventListener("mouseover", lightUp, false);
}
function lightUp()
{
    h1[i].style.textShadow = "2px 2px 5px blue";
}
```

But this just doesn't do anything when I hover over the h1 element that I am using, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong *if I add a () after the lightUp, it immediately runs the function without me hovering over.*
Also, there is nothing wrong with the for loop, when I applied the text shadow without the hovering, it applied it to all h1 elements, it is something wrong with the listener I think.

Comment: `i <= h1.length` - apart from not using your previously cached length (premature optimization btw), that's an off-by-one, and should give an error in your console. The last iteration will be at `h1[h1.length]`, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend switching from index-based looping to `for...of` instead, which is much more readable:

```js
const headlines = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (const headline of headlines) {
    headline.addEventListener("mouseover", lightUp, false);
}

function lightUp(event) {
  event.target.style.textShadow = "2px 2px 5px blue";
}
```

```html
<h1>Foo</h1>
<h1>Bar</h1>
<h1>Baz</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, and it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your lightUp function shouldn't rely on the `i` variable you're using to add the listeners for a variety of reasons. It should either get the h1 from the event, as in:

```js
function lightUp(event) {
  event.target.style.textShadow = "2px 2px 5px blue";
}
```

Or be bound when you add the listener, as in:

```js
h1[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => lightUp(h1[i]), false);
```

```js
function lightUp(element)
{
  element.style.textShadow = "2px 2px 5px blue";
}
```

---

After your for loop runs, the value of `i` is going to be `h1.length + 1`, so your `lightUp` function is always going to attempt to operate on a nonexistent h1. (I would expect this to throw an exception: attempting to access `.style` on `undefined`.)